# Adding paramater to SQL command in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to get the following code to work:

```
String connStr = sqlRoutines.connectionString;
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
sqlConn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TABEL=@tabel";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@tabel", SqlDbType.Text).Value = DataContainer.sqlTabel;
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
Console.WriteLine(reader.FieldCount.ToString());
reader.Close();
sqlConn.Close();
```

Somehow the value "DataContainer.sqlTabel" is not added to the command. Am I missing something here?

Whenever I use `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM" + DataContainer.sqlTabel;` everything is working fine. However I want to avoid this method because of the SQL Injection.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I want to achieve a command that uses a variable (which is changed by the user). So I want to have something like this: `SELECT * FROM * a variable defined by the use *;`. When I use:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM @tablename";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@tablename", SqlDbType.Text).Value = DataContainer.sqlTabel;
```

It doesn't work as well.

Comment: You can't parameterize table names, you can parameterize **only** values.

Comment: Aha that's why! Is there any workaround so I can select the right table via a command? I am indeed using the "using" statement. Just to make it easier I didn't put it in the code I provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you try to parameterize table name which you **can't**. I don't understand what is `TABEL` either. [`FROM` (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) doesn't have a syntax like that.

You can only parameterize **values**. Not table names or column names. Specify the table name as part of the SQL. But when you do that, you need very strong validation on the table name before putting it into the SQL, or have a whitelisted set of valid table names, in order to avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

If you really want to parameterize it, you can use (but not recommended) Dynamic SQL.

[SELECT * FROM @tablename](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_table)

> As we have seen, we can make this procedure work with help of dynamic
>   SQL, but it should also be clear that we gain none of the advantages
>   with generating that dynamic SQL in a stored procedure. You could just
>   as well send the dynamic SQL from the client. So, OK: 1) if the SQL
>   statement is very complex, you save some network traffic and you do
>   encapsulation. 2) As we have seen, starting with SQL 2005 there are
>   methods to deal with permissions. **Nevertheless, this is a bad idea**.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections.

```
using(SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
using(SqlCommand cmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand())
{
   ...
   ...
   using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: @WonderTiger What is _not working_ exactly? You said `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + DataContainer.sqlTabel;` works fine. I suggested this way either but a strong validation on user side or a white list of table names.

Comment: Well, our databases can contain more than one table. The user selects a specific table he/she wants to retrieve from the database. That's why I have to specify which table I want to retrieve in the Command. If it can't be done I'll have to go with the cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + DataContainer.sqlTabel; But I will take a look at the Stored Procedures first. Thank you!

Comment: @WonderTiger Yes, as I said in my answer, you need to use it as a part of SQL. But please do some strong validation on it.

Answer (score 0):

we can't use parameters for either table name or column name. parameters only limited for values. if you want to use parameter for table name then you've to create a stored procedure and then pass the table name as parameter to store procedure. more information can be found here

[Table name as parameter](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/257322/Pass-tablename-as-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. You can only use dynamic SQL. You need to decide for yourself whether SQL injection is a risk and if so you need to code for this, perhaps checking that the value of table doesn't contain anything other than a valid table name. You can check the table name against the system tables to ensure it is valid.